# Prerequisites for reading Gregory Perelman's work

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, ricci-flow

What are the prerequisites for understanding the work of Perelman concerning the Poincaré conjecture?

I am referring to the last three papers [here](http://arxiv.org/find/math/1/au:+Perelman_G/0/1/0/all/0/1).

Comment: A simple Google search yields this: https://math.berkeley.edu/~lott/ricciflow/perelman.html .

Comment: The answers to this [question](http://mathoverflow.net/q/37595/8887) are relevant.

Comment: Terry Tao gave a course on Perelman's proof of the Poincare conjecture. The notes for this course were written up on his blog, under the tag *285G*. The first of the lectures is here: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/03/26/285g-lecture-0-riemannian-manifolds-and-curvature/

Comment: Try going through (that book itself has more prerequisites that you'll have to acquire on the way): Morgan, John; Tian, Gang Ricci flow and the Poincaré conjecture. Clay Mathematics Monographs, 3. American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI; Clay Mathematics Institute, Cambridge, MA, 2007. xlii+521 pp.